# How can I filter out instances of a subclass?

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to display all `Event` objects, but only one specific instance if it is also a `RecurringEvent`.

**models.py**

```py
from slugify import slugify

from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import render

from home.models import TimestampedModel, NewsItem
from locations.models import Location
from .managers import EventManager, RecurringEventManager, RepeatInfoManager

class Event(NewsItem):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    all_day = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_start = models.DateTimeField()
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = EventManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class RecurringEvent(Event):
    info = models.ForeignKey('RepeatInfo', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    objects = RecurringEventManager()

class RepeatInfo(TimestampedModel):
    FREQUENCY_UNITS_CHOICES = [
        (0, 'No Repeat'),
        (1, 'Day(s)'),
        (2, 'Week(s)'),
        (3, 'Month(s)'),
        (4, 'Year(s)'),
    ]
    ENDS_CHOICES = [
        (0, 'Ends after maximum duration (1 year)'),
        (1, 'Ends on date'),
        (2, 'Ends after number of occurences'),
    ]

    weekly = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    frequency = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    frequency_units = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, choices=FREQUENCY_UNITS_CHOICES)
    ends = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, choices=ENDS_CHOICES)
    ends_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    ends_after = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    objects = RepeatInfoManager()
```

I've tried the following:

```py
events = []
_events = Event.objects.filter(date_start__gte=datetime.utcnow())
recurring_events_info = []
for event in _events:
    if isinstance(event, RecurringEvent):
        if event.info not in recurring_events_info:
            recurring_event = RecurringEvent.objects.filter(date_start__gte=datetime.utcnow(), info=event.info).order_by('-date_start').first()
            events.append(recurring_event)
            recurring_events_info.append(event.info)
    else:
        events.append(event)
```

but the `isinstance(event, RecurringEvent)` check always fails. How can I get only `Event`s that are NOT `RecurringEvent`s, so I can combine them with `RecurringEvent`s obtained this way?

```py
events = []
recurring_events = RecurringEvent.objects.filter(date_start__gte=datetime.utcnow())
recurring_events_info = []
for event in recurring_events:
    if event.info not in recurring_events_info:
        recurring_event = RecurringEvent.objects.filter(date_start__gte=datetime.utcnow(), info=event.info).order_by('-date_start').first()
        events.append(recurring_event)
        recurring_events_info.append(event.info)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.__class__.__base__` on your `Event` objects to examine their parent type.

```
for event in _events:
    # This checks if event object is a RecurringEvent (i.e. its parent is Event)
    if event.__class__.__base__ == Event:
        print('RecurringEvent object')
    # Otherwise its parent is not Event (i.e. it's not RecurrentEvent)
    else:
        print('Not RecurringEvent object')
```

You may instead put an `elif` with a check whether the base class is `NewsItem` as well, but I'm not aware of other parts of your code.

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: This doesn't help because `event.__class__.__base__` is always a `NewsItem`.